# execution with ARM NEON takes longer than C code

Tags: arm, sse, neon, intrinsics

I converted a Brisk function (to resize an image) from SSE intrinsics to ARM NEON intrinsics in order to execute it on ARM architecture. Brisk uses the SSE function if supported, otherwise uses an opencv function. The SSE one is of course faster.
I converted step by step the SSE function in ARM neon but when I measure the execution time compared to the one of the openCV resize function the result is that my function is slower.(0.2ms vs 0.4ms). Here is the code:

SSE:

```
inline void BriskLayer::halfsample(const cv::Mat& srcimg, cv::Mat& dstimg){
const unsigned short leftoverCols = ((srcimg.cols%16)/2);// take care with border...
const bool noleftover = (srcimg.cols%16)==0; // note: leftoverCols can be zero butthis still false...

// make sure the destination image is of the right size:
assert(srcimg.cols/2==dstimg.cols);
assert(srcimg.rows/2==dstimg.rows);

// mask needed later:
register __m128i mask = _mm_set_epi32 (0x00FF00FF, 0x00FF00FF, 0x00FF00FF, 0x00FF00FF);
// to be added in order to make successive averaging correct:
register __m128i ones = _mm_set_epi32 (0x11111111, 0x11111111, 0x11111111, 0x11111111);

// data pointers:
__m128i* p1=(__m128i*)srcimg.data;
__m128i* p2=(__m128i*)(srcimg.data+srcimg.cols);
__m128i* p_dest=(__m128i*)dstimg.data;
unsigned char* p_dest_char;//=(unsigned char*)p_dest;

// size:
const unsigned int size = (srcimg.cols*srcimg.rows)/16;
const unsigned int hsize = srcimg.cols/16;
__m128i* p_end=p1+size;
unsigned int row=0;
const unsigned int end=hsize/2;
bool half_end;
if(hsize%2==0)
    half_end=false;
else
    half_end=true;
while(p2<p_end){
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<end;i++){
        // load the two blocks of memory:
        __m128i upper;
        __m128i lower;
        if(noleftover){
            upper=_mm_load_si128(p1);
            lower=_mm_load_si128(p2);
        }
        else{
            upper=_mm_loadu_si128(p1);
            lower=_mm_loadu_si128(p2);
        }

        __m128i result1=_mm_adds_epu8 (upper, ones);
        result1=_mm_avg_epu8 (upper, lower);

        // increment the pointers:
        p1++;
        p2++;

        // load the two blocks of memory:
        upper=_mm_loadu_si128(p1);
        lower=_mm_loadu_si128(p2);
        __m128i result2=_mm_adds_epu8 (upper, ones);
        result2=_mm_avg_epu8 (upper, lower);
        // calculate the shifted versions:
        __m128i result1_shifted = _mm_srli_si128 (result1, 1);
        __m128i result2_shifted = _mm_srli_si128 (result2, 1);
        // pack:
        __m128i result=_mm_packus_epi16 (_mm_and_si128 (result1, mask),
                _mm_and_si128 (result2, mask));
        __m128i result_shifted = _mm_packus_epi16 (_mm_and_si128 (result1_shifted, mask),
                _mm_and_si128 (result2_shifted, mask));
        // average for the second time:
        result=_mm_avg_epu8(result,result_shifted);

        // store to memory
        _mm_storeu_si128 (p_dest, result);

        // increment the pointers:
        p1++;
        p2++;
        p_dest++;
        //p_dest_char=(unsigned char*)p_dest;
    }
    // if we are not at the end of the row, do the rest:
    if(half_end){
        // load the two blocks of memory:
        __m128i upper;
        __m128i lower;
        if(noleftover){
            upper=_mm_load_si128(p1);
            lower=_mm_load_si128(p2);
        }
        else{
            upper=_mm_loadu_si128(p1);
            lower=_mm_loadu_si128(p2);
        }

        __m128i result1=_mm_adds_epu8 (upper, ones);
        result1=_mm_avg_epu8 (upper, lower);

        // increment the pointers:
        p1++;
        p2++;

        // compute horizontal pairwise average and store
        p_dest_char=(unsigned char*)p_dest;
        const UCHAR_ALIAS* result=(UCHAR_ALIAS*)&result1;
        for(unsigned int j=0; j<8; j++){
            *(p_dest_char++)=(*(result+2*j)+*(result+2*j+1))/2;
        }
        //p_dest_char=(unsigned char*)p_dest;
    }
    else{
        p_dest_char=(unsigned char*)p_dest;
    }

    if(noleftover){
        row++;
        p_dest=(__m128i*)(dstimg.data+row*dstimg.cols);
        p1=(__m128i*)(srcimg.data+2*row*srcimg.cols);
        //p2=(__m128i*)(srcimg.data+(2*row+1)*srcimg.cols);
        //p1+=hsize;
        p2=p1+hsize;
    }
    else{
        const unsigned char* p1_src_char=(unsigned char*)(p1);
        const unsigned char* p2_src_char=(unsigned char*)(p2);
        for(unsigned int k=0; k<leftoverCols; k++){
            unsigned short tmp = p1_src_char[k]+p1_src_char[k+1]+
                    p2_src_char[k]+p2_src_char[k+1];
            *(p_dest_char++)=(unsigned char)(tmp/4);
        }
        // done with the two rows:
        row++;
        p_dest=(__m128i*)(dstimg.data+row*dstimg.cols);
        p1=(__m128i*)(srcimg.data+2*row*srcimg.cols);
        p2=(__m128i*)(srcimg.data+(2*row+1)*srcimg.cols);
    }
}
```

}

ARM NEON:

```
void halfsample(const cv::Mat& srcimg, cv::Mat& dstimg){
const unsigned short leftoverCols = ((srcimg.cols%16)/2);// take care with border...
const bool noleftover = (srcimg.cols%16)==0; // note: leftoverCols can be zero but this still false...

// make sure the destination image is of the right size:
//assert(srcimg.cols/2==dstimg.cols);
//assert(srcimg.rows/2==dstimg.rows);
//int32x4_t zero = vdupq_n_s8(0);

// mask needed later:
//register __m128i mask = _mm_set_epi32 (0x00FF00FF, 0x00FF00FF, 0x00FF00FF, 0x00FF00FF);
int32x4_t mask = vdupq_n_s32(0x00FF00FF);
// to be added in order to make successive averaging correct:
int32x4_t ones = vdupq_n_s32(0x11111111);
    print128_numhex(mask);
// data pointers:
int32_t* p1=(int32_t*)srcimg.data;
int32_t* p2=(int32_t*)(srcimg.data+srcimg.cols);
int32_t* p_dest=(int32_t*)dstimg.data;
unsigned char* p_dest_char;//=(unsigned char*)p_dest;
int k=0;
// size:
const unsigned int size = (srcimg.cols*srcimg.rows)/16;
const unsigned int hsize = srcimg.cols/16;
int32_t* p_end=p1+size*4;
unsigned int row=0;
const unsigned int end=hsize/2;
bool half_end;
if(hsize%2==0)
    half_end=false;
else
    half_end=true;
while(p2<p_end){
    k++;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<end;i++){
        // load the two blocks of memory:
        int32x4_t upper;
        int32x4_t lower;
        if(noleftover){
            upper=vld1q_s32(p1);
            lower=vld1q_s32(p2);
        }
        else{
            upper=vld1q_s32(p1);
            lower=vld1q_s32(p2);
        }

        int32x4_t result1=vaddq_s32(upper, ones);
        result1=vrhaddq_u8(upper, lower);

        // increment the pointers:
        p1=p1+4;
        p2=p2+4;

        // load the two blocks of memory:
        upper=vld1q_s32(p1);
        lower=vld1q_s32(p2);
        int32x4_t result2=vaddq_s32(upper, ones);
        result2=vrhaddq_u8(upper, lower);
        // calculate the shifted versions:
        int32x4_t result1_shifted = vextq_u8(result1,vmovq_n_u8(0),1);
        int32x4_t result2_shifted = vextq_u8(result2,vmovq_n_u8(0),1);
        // pack:
        int32x4_t result= vcombine_u8(vqmovn_u16(vandq_u32(result1, mask)),
                vqmovn_u16(vandq_u32 (result2, mask)));

        int32x4_t result_shifted =  vcombine_u8(vqmovn_u16(vandq_u32 (result1_shifted, mask)),
                vqmovn_u16(vandq_u32(result2_shifted, mask)));
        // average for the second time:
        result=vrhaddq_u8(result,result_shifted);

        // store to memory
        vst1q_s32(p_dest, result);

        // increment the pointers:
        p1=p1+4;
        p2=p2+4;
        p_dest=p_dest+4;
        //p_dest_char=(unsigned char*)p_dest;
    }
    // if we are not at the end of the row, do the rest:
    if(half_end){
        std::cout<<"entra in half_end" << std::endl;
        // load the two blocks of memory:
        int32x4_t upper;
        int32x4_t lower;
        if(noleftover){
            upper=vld1q_s32(p1);
            lower=vld1q_s32(p2);
        }
        else{
            upper=vld1q_s32(p1);
            lower=vld1q_s32(p2);
        }

        int32x4_t result1=vqaddq_s32(upper, ones);
        result1=vrhaddq_u8(upper, lower);

        // increment the pointers:
        p1=p1+4;
        p2=p2+4;

        // compute horizontal pairwise average and store
        p_dest_char=(unsigned char*)p_dest;
        const UCHAR_ALIAS* result=(UCHAR_ALIAS*)&result1;
        for(unsigned int j=0; j<8; j++){
            *(p_dest_char++)=(*(result+2*j)+*(result+2*j+1))/2;
        }
        //p_dest_char=(unsigned char*)p_dest;
    }
    else{
        p_dest_char=(unsigned char*)p_dest;
    }

    if(noleftover){
        row++;
        p_dest=(int32_t*)(dstimg.data+row*dstimg.cols);
        p1=(int32_t*)(srcimg.data+2*row*srcimg.cols);
        //p2=(__m128i*)(srcimg.data+(2*row+1)*srcimg.cols);
        //p1+=hsize;
        p2=p1+hsize*4;
    }
    else{
        const unsigned char* p1_src_char=(unsigned char*)(p1);
        const unsigned char* p2_src_char=(unsigned char*)(p2);
        for(unsigned int k=0; k<leftoverCols; k++){
            unsigned short tmp = p1_src_char[k]+p1_src_char[k+1]+
                    p2_src_char[k]+p2_src_char[k+1];
            *(p_dest_char++)=(unsigned char)(tmp/4);
        }
        // done with the two rows:
        row++;
        p_dest=(int32_t*)(dstimg.data+row*dstimg.cols);
        p1=(int32_t*)(srcimg.data+2*row*srcimg.cols);
        p2=(int32_t*)(srcimg.data+(2*row+1)*srcimg.cols);
    }
}
```

}

The outputs of the ARM and SSE functions are exactly the same. The problem is the execution time.

Comment: You should start with improving the code. First `noleftover` part is same for if/else. You assign `result1` twice without using first one. Don't use shorts since ARM has 32 bit words. Most of this might be optimized by compiler but anyway you should clear those then use a profiler like `DS-5 Streamline` - that should make your task easier. A community/free version is available.

Comment: @auselen Yes in the leftover part I copied 2 times my code. I edited it.Regarding result1, I did exactly as in the original code, and it's still not clear to me why that operation is done, I just converted it as it is.I'll try that profiler like you said.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. So I assume you got fooled by some ifdefs.

Comment: @auselen I'm sure it compile. I use these parameters -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -flax-vector-conversions. The problem with prifiling with DS-5 Streamline is that I'm using a beagleboard (without graphical interface) and I don't know if I can use DS-5 on it.

Comment: You can capture data on beaglebone and check it on a PC host, very easy.

Comment: Try your code here http://gcc.godbolt.org

Comment: I have problems trying the code there because of openCV libraries. Anyway I measured execution times of single instructions just to get an idea and there is no clear bottleneck in my code.

Comment: @auselen I have been using a beaglebone with Ubuntu.I tried running my code on another beaglebone with Angstrom and the results were completely different. My code is much faster on Angstrom. How come? Is it the different compiler?

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that neither intrinsics nor inline-assembly codes can be nearly as "flawless" as hand written ones in native assembly.

Even worse, sometimes the compiler -especially the opensource ones like GCC- puts some unnecessary instructions that cause pipeline stalls which costs far over ten cycles. When this occurs within the inner most loop, it's straight fatal for the performance.

Why don't you post the disassembly of your code? People having problems with intrinscs should always take a look at it first. (And stop using intrinsics ASAP)

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: I'll make it to an answer when the OP posts his disassembly :)

Comment: How do I obtain the disassembly (It's my firts time using NEON)?